# State change not carrying over in react navigating to new page

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a program that where the user enters their login and password on one page, and then, if their login is legit, is sent to another page where their username is displayed.

I have an index page:

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Login from './Login';
import CreateAccount from "./CreateAccount";
import Lab from "./Lab";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

function App(){

 

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");

    return(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
      
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Login setUser = {(user_name) => setCurrentUser(user_name)} />} />
        <Route exact path="/create_account" element={<CreateAccount /> } />
        <Route exact path="/lab" element={<Lab user = {currentUser}/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    )
}
```

A login page:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

function Login({setUser}) {

const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");



function checkCredentials(){
  console.log("function firing")

fetch("http://localhost:8000/getAccounts").then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);


let isUser = false


for (let x of data)
{


if (x.username == username)
{
  isUser = true;


  if(x.password == password)
  {
    alert("Loggin in...")

setUser(username);


window.location = "/lab";
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Wrong password")
  }

}

}

if(isUser == false)
{
 alert("Not a user, please check the username you entered or create an account")
}
})

}

  return (
    <div>
      Login: <input type = "text" onChange ={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}/>
      <br />
      <br />
      Password: <input type = "password" onChange = {(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}/>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={checkCredentials}>Login</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <span style = {{fontSize: "75%"}}>New user?  <Link to = "/create_account">Create account</Link></span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

And the landing page for after you log in, called the lab.

```
    function Lab(props){

    return(
        <div>Hello {props.user}, welcome to your alchemy lab</div>
        )
}

export default Lab;
```

The problem is, nothing ever shows up in the props.user feild.